# Is there a way to have multiple windows logins go to single session?

Tags: windows, session, authentication

In windows 7, is there a way to have every login go to the same user session. So when a person is met with the login screen, they login and can continue working on that same user session. I am asking this because each user has their own login, but on this machine I need a program to be running across all user sessions. Since that doesn't seem feasible, I was just going to have them all login to the same user session.

Is this possible?

Comment: You could create a local account and configure the machine to log in automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way to solve this would be to have the program run as a service, and have a client UI that loads on startup 'hook' into the service process.   Loading multiple users to the same session space would effectively violate the entire windows security model.

So, you either need to use a shared user for this, or a shared process (either local as a service, or remote as a server)

Comment: The program I need to run is a third party application with no api where I could make our own gui. I am guessing there isn't a way to make a full blown gui app a service?

Comment: It is possible to have multiple users in the same session using `runas`.  It does not "violate the entire windows security model".  (Vista's UIPI is designed to make this scenario more secure)  However, I don't think you can log in multiple users to one session.

Comment: True, but that's backwards to the model I believe the original poster was asking, which I read as having multiple users externally connect into the same session, which really isn't possible.

That said - you may be on to something - @Justin, what are the constraints on the program? Does it need to be persistently running,  can there only be a single instance on the machine? Or could you perhaps create a local user that is defined in the shortut as the 'runas' user, and have everyone launch that link?

Comment: Each user has their own username & password in which they login to this single machine. I want one of them to be able to start a program and have it processing. Then some days later someone else can login to their own seperate account and use this program.

Answer (score 0):

So, there's one possible way you might be able to get this to work, and that's to set this up as an interactive service.   Definitely not a secure way to keep your system, but if you are able to make it work, it should work for your purposes:

Interactive services (in particular, read 'using an interactive service'):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx

Making srvany.exe (to run non-services as a service) on Windows7/Windows 2008:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverMigration/thread/98a97aee-c62b-4683-94ab-3777899cf7de/